# The multi part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

I am getting this error while running following query

```
SELECT
    T2.[AcctCode],
    T2.[AcctName],
    T5.[Name],
    SUM(T0.[Debit]) AS Actual,
    SUM(T3.[DebLTotal]) AS Budget
FROM [dbo].[JDT1] T0
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[OJDT] T1
         ON T0.[TransId] = T1.[TransId]
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[OACT] T2
         ON T0.[Account] = T2.[AcctCode],
     [dbo].[OBGT] T#
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[BGT1] T4
         ON T3.[AbsId] = T4.[BudgId]
     INNER JOIN OBGS T5
         ON T3.[Instance] = T5.[AbsId]
WHERE T2.[AcctName] LIKE '%Travel%'
AND T5.[Name] LIKE 'Main Budget 2015'
GROUP BY T2.[AcctCode], T2.[AcctName], T5.[Name]
```

Comment: `ON T0.[Account] = T2.[AcctCode],[dbo].[OBGT] T# ` CROSS JOIN?

Comment: `T5.[Name] LIKE 'Main Budget 2015'`  like without wildcards? then there is no need for `LIKE` --> `T5.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'`

Comment: @CeOnSql I removed LIKE but still getting :                                       Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "T3.AbsId" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "T3.Instance" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "T3.DebLTotal" could not be bound.

Comment: that's because none of your tables has the alias `T3` !?!?!

Comment: Thanks @CeOnSql .. I got it